# Facebook stream publish dialog buttons event not working in IE

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, fbjs

Facebook `fb.ui` for `feed` prompts fine, however when clicked on **Share** or **Cancel** button, the event is not triggered in IE only, works fine in other browsers such as Chrome, Firefox, etc.

Here is the code:

```
function showStreamPublish()
{
    FB.ui(
    {
    'method': 'feed',
    'name': 'xxxxxx',
    'link': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'picture': 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'description': 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'app_id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    },
    function(response)
    {
        alert(response); //**** this does not work in IE
    });
}
```

Any workaround this or whether this is facebook bug ?

Comment: What versions of IE have you tested?

Comment: why are you adding the app_id in the call - you already specified the app_id in the `FB.init` function - it is not needed here.  Are you able to make any other calls to `FB.ui` and receive the callback?

Comment: @Lix: Feed dialog shows fine, no not using any other dialog

Comment: can you try using a different `FB.ui` method? `apprequests` for example... see if you get a callback from that.

Comment: Have you tried to provide "Channel File" to `FB.init`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments above you should have a channel file.  Also, for IE compatibility, you may need to set a privacy header (aka p3p).  See http://www.admon.org/how-to-implement-p3p-http-headers-for-cross-site-cookies/